# JS micro-view library

Tags: javascript, html, security, library, dom

I created a JS view micro-library not too long ago it's named contours. Its primary purpose is element creation. It has some similarities to ReactJS. It lacks many features that React has like server side rendering virtual dom and the like. It is also a much smaller scope as it only cares about creating things for the dom and not updating them (with updating being done in contours the classic jQuery way).

But the need being filled is that it works well with existing jQuery projects, but keep in mind jQuery is by no means required or a dependency. In fact, contours is dependency free. One drawback is currently for browser support you need to add ES6 support through babel as it uses ES6 template strings.

The following is some code as per the docs:

```js
// if this were plain ES6 this would be an import statement.
var contours = contours.default;

var userData = [
  {
    name: "Joe Jackson",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/40x40"
  },
  {
    name: "Jessica Jackson",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/40x40"
  },
  {
    name: "Jimmy Jones",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/40x40"
  },
];

document.body.appendChild(contours`
  <div class="userlist">
    ${userData.map(function (user) {
      return contours`
      <div>
        <img ${contours.attributes({src: user.picture })}>
          ${contours.textNode(user.name)}
      </div>
      `;
    })}
  </div>
`);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/johnsonjo4531/contours/master/dist/contours.js"></script>
```

[Here's](http://jsbin.com/surehi/1/edit?html,js,console,output) a working JSBin if the above code snippet didn't work for you.

The above appends a list of users to the body. Notice how contours is appending a text node. This is important, because like JavaScript's `.innerHTML()` and the common jQuery function's HTML creator it is not inherently safe to just put user content into this function, because it will be coerced to HTML. Thus to prevent XSS from user created content you must insert text nodes. Contours works well with many DOM Element types and can insert them into the markup anywhere a regular DOM Element can be inserted.

The reason you would want to use a text node is to prevent XSS vulnerabilities. Same with the attributes method it inserts an attribute onto the element (at any place an attribute can go ([think opening HTML tags)) yet again the reason you want to use this and not just the contours function is for preventing XSS vulnerabilities. Contours actually build a string of your HTML first replacing interpolated nodes and attributes with placeholders, and then replaces the placeholders with the actual content.

After the execution of the code above your body will appear like so:

```
<body>
  ...
  <div class="userlist">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
      Joe Jackson
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
      Jessica Jackson
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
      Jimmy Jones
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The project exists [here](https://github.com/johnsonjo4531/contours). You can check out the docs hopefully they are clear on intent. I should probably create some example applications that could be made with it.

Here's the main files ES6 code:

**/src-es6/contours.js**

```
// from mdn
if (!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function(arg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
  };
}

// from mdn
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  Object.assign = function(target) {
    'use strict';
    if (target == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
    }

    target = Object(target);
    for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
      var source = arguments[index];
      if (source != null) {
        for (var key in source) {
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
            target[key] = source[key];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return target;
  };
}

if(!Object.entries) {
  Object.entries = function (obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
      return [key, obj[key]];
    });
  }
}

var contours = (function contour () {
  var jQueryTemp = typeof jQuery !== "undefined" ? jQuery : function noJQuery () {};

  // var __entityMap = {
  //     "&": "&amp;",
  //     "<": "&lt;",
  //     ">": "&gt;",
  //     '"': '&quot;',
  //     "'": '&#39;',
  //     "/": '&#x2F;'
  // };
  //
  // function escapeHTML (str) {
  //     return str.replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {
  //         return __entityMap[s];
  //     });
  // }

  function escapeHTML(str){
        // this is a basic parser
        var b = "";
        for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
            var c = str.charAt(i);
            if (c == "&") b += "&amp;";
            else if (c == "<") b += "&lt;";
            else if (c == ">") b += "&gt;";
            else if (c == '"') b += "&quot;";
            else if (c == "'") b += "&#39;";
            else if (c == "/") b += "&#x2F;";
            else b += c;
        }
        return b;
    }

  function parseHTML (markup) {
    markup = markup.trim();
    let el = document.createElement("template");
    el.innerHTML = markup;
    return el.content.childNodes;
  }

  function getReplaceText(strings, index) {
    return '<template class="contours-shouldBeUnique"></template>';
  }

  function getNode (nodeValues, attributeValues, value, strings, index) {
    var i, html = "";
    if(value || value === 0) {
      if(value instanceof Node) {
        html += getReplaceText(strings, index);
        nodeValues.push(value);
      } else if(value instanceof jQueryTemp) {
        html += getReplaceText(strings, index);
        nodeValues.push(value);
      } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        for(i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
          html += getNode(nodeValues, attributeValues, value[i], strings, index);
        }
      } else if (value instanceof NodeList || value instanceof HTMLCollection) {
        value = [].slice.call(value);
        for(i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
          html += getNode(nodeValues, attributeValues, value[i], strings, index);
        }
      } else if (value !== null && typeof value === "object" && value["__contours_attributes__"]) {
        html += " data-contours-attrs ";
        delete value["__contours_attributes__"];
        attributeValues.push(value);
      } else {
        html += value;
      }
    }
    return html;
  }

  function DOMTemplate (strings, values, options = {}) {
    var defaults = {
      includeScripts: false
    };

    options = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);

    let html = '',
        nodeValues = [],
        attributeValues = [],
        node,
        nodes,
        replaceNodes,
        replace,
        replacement;

    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
      let string = strings[i];
      let value = values[i];
      let prev2Chars = string.slice(-2);
      if(prev2Chars == "$#") {
        value = contours.textNode(value);
        string = string.slice(0, -2);
      } else if (prev2Chars == "$@") {
        value = contours.attributes(value);
        string = string.slice(0, -2);
      } else if (string.slice(-1) == "$") {
        value = contours.escapeHTML(value);
        string = string.slice(0, -1);
      }

      html += string;

      html += getNode(nodeValues, attributeValues, value, strings, i);
    }
    html += strings[i];

    nodes = parseHTML(html);
    let arrNodes = [].slice.call(nodes);
    for(let i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
      traverseDOM(arrNodes[i], nodeValues.slice(), attributeValues.slice(), options);
    }
    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    let length = nodes.length;
    for(let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
      fragment.appendChild(nodes[0]);
    }
    return fragment;

  }

  function traverseDOM (node, nodeValues, attributeValues, options) {
    var notReplaced = true;
    var replacement;
    if(attributeValues.length === 0 && nodeValues.length === 0 && !options.includeScripts) {
      return;
    }

    if(node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      if(node.className === "contours-shouldBeUnique") {
        if(nodeValues.length > 0) {
          replacement = nodeValues.shift();
          if(replacement instanceof jQueryTemp) {
            jQueryTemp(node).replaceWith(replacement);
          } else {
            node.parentNode.replaceChild(replacement, node);
          }
        }
      } else {
        if(node.hasAttribute("data-contours-attrs")) {
          if(attributeValues.length > 0) {
            setAttributes(node, attributeValues.shift());
            node.removeAttribute("data-contours-attrs");
          }
        }
        if (options.includeScripts && (node.tagName || "").toUpperCase() === 'SCRIPT') {
          node.parentNode.replaceChild( nodeScriptClone(node) , node );
        }
      }

      if(notReplaced) {
        var i        = 0;
        var children = node.childNodes;
        while ( i < children.length ) {
          traverseDOM( children[i++], nodeValues, attributeValues, options );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function nodeScriptClone(node){
    var script  = document.createElement("script");
    script.text = node.innerHTML;
    for( var i = node.attributes.length-1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
      script.setAttribute( node.attributes[i].name, node.attributes[i].value );
    }
    return script;
  }

  function setAttributesAll (nodes, attributeValues) {
    var j = 0;
    nodes.forEach(function (el) {
      if(typeof el.getElementsByClassName === "function") {j
        var uniqueEls = [].slice.call(el.querySelectorAll("[data-contours-attrs]"));
        if(el.hasAttribute("data-contours-attrs")) {
          uniqueEls.push(el);
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < uniqueEls.length; ++i, ++j) {
          setAttributes(uniqueEls[i], attributeValues[j]);
          uniqueEls[i].removeAttribute("data-contours-attrs");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function partition (list,cb) {
    if(typeof cb === "function") {
        let results = [];
        results.push([]);
        results.push([]);

        let testPassing = function (condition, val) {
          if(condition) {
            results[0].push(val);
          } else {
            results[1].push(val);
          }
        }


      if(typeof list === "object" && !Array.isArray(list)) {
        Object.keys(list).forEach(function (key) {
          var obj = {};
          obj[key] = list[key];
          testPassing(cb(list[key], key, list), obj);
        });
      } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
          testPassing(cb(list[i], i, list), list[i]);
        }
      }
      return results;
    }
  }

  var fromCamelToKabobCase = str => str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1").toLowerCase();

  function setAttributes (elNode, attributes = {}) {
    var style, styleString;
    if(attributes.style && typeof attributes.style === "object") {
      style = attributes.style;
      delete attributes.style;
      styleString = Object.keys(style).map(function (key) {
        return `${fromCamelToKabobCase(key)}: ${style[key]};`;
      }).join(" ");
      elNode.setAttribute("style", styleString);
    }
    var allAttributes = Object.entries(attributes);
    for(var i = 0; i < allAttributes.length; ++i) {
      var [key, val] = allAttributes[i];
      if(/^on/.test(key)) {
        if (typeof val === "function") {
          elNode.addEventListener(key.replace(/^on/, ""), val);
        } else {
          console.warn(key + " property does not have a function for a value");
        }
      } else {
        try {
          elNode.setAttribute(key, val);
        } catch (e) {
          console.warn(e);
        }
      }
    }

    return elNode;
  }

  function _contours (html, ...values) {
    return DOMTemplate(html, values);
  }

  function custom (options) {
    return function _contoursCustom (html, ...values) {
      return DOMTemplate(html, values, options);
    };
  }

  function attributes (obj) {
    return Object.assign({}, obj, {
      "__contours_attributes__": true
    });
  }

  return Object.assign(_contours, {
    escapeHTML: escapeHTML,
    textNode: function (text) {
      return document.createTextNode(text);
    },
    custom: custom,
    attributes: attributes
  });
}());

export default contours;

var {escapeHTML, textNode, custom, attributes} = contours;

export {
  escapeHTML,
  textNode,
  custom,
  attributes
}
```

Any comments, suggestions, security-vulnerabilties, improvements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question,

I just looked at Contours.js, the first thing that hit my eye was your HTML escaping code, it is both lacking and trying too hard ;) I would counter-propose

```
function escapeHtml(str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Furthermore, consider running jshint (jshint.com) on your code, you have missing semi-colons, unused variables, and one unorthodox accessor.

Other than that

- You have zero lines of (useful) comments, the code is not obvious enough for that
- I don't know if there is a browser that can parse this:

  ```
    var {escapeHTML, textNode, custom, attributes} = contours;
  ```

  without also having `isArray`, `assign` etc. I would suggest to either drop the fancy code or the shims ;)
- `getReplaceText` while funny does not seem to make sense?
- if(typeof el.getElementsByClassName === "function") {**j** is breaking your code
- `"data-contours-attrs"` and variations on this probably should be constants